# Behavior of number_format() across 5.3 & 5.4

Tags: php

I have an issue on using `number_format` on version 5.3 and 5.4 versions

> $number = 1234.56;
>   echo number_format($number, 2, '.', " ");

In 5.3 gives the output is **1&234.56**
But in 5.4 the output is **1 234.56**

can anyone suggest me a solution for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) would have told you the differences between 5.3 and 5.4:

> Changelog

```
Version    Description
5.4.0      This function now supports multiple bytes in dec_point and thousands_sep.
           Only the first byte of each separator was used in older versions.
```

And your thousands separator ***is*** a multibyte character